# Installing Canopy in OSX and Linux in same home directory

Tags: enthought

I have a networked home directory, which is used by linux and OSX machines. I want to install the linux and OSX versions of Canopy so that I can use it from any machine.

I first installed the linux version by running the '.sh' file. Despite asking where I wanted to put Canopy, the installer puts most of the stuff in `~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/`. This is a problem because later, when I try to install Canopy in OSX, it just assumes again that Canopy is in `~/Library/Enthought` so somethings will be overwritten but other binaries will be kept untouched, and the whole thing doesn't work in OSX or Linux.

Is there a way to force the linux version to be installed somewhere else? From the documentation it seems that it used to be `~/Enthought`, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with having your locations.cfg file in `~/.canopy` which is shared by both the versions of Canopy.  Can you try the following:

1. Install the Linux version of Canopy and run it.
2. Remove your `~/.canopy/locations.cfg`
3. Install your OSX version, and see if that works?
4. When you go back to running your Linux version, it'll again prompt you for install locations for the user environment, where you could select the old Linux install location.

Even if this works, I'm not sure, this would be too convenient.  Let me know, how it goes. :)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I didn't know about `~/.canopy`. Perhaps you can add it to the uninstallation instructions? I played around with the `~/.canopy` directory and `locations.cfg` and could indeed install the Linux version to a different directory. However, installing on the Mac still fails. I get the same "failed to set up your environment" bug that I've always had in this machine (see ticket #10867), so no Canopy here.